# fadeOut() one table, fadeIn() another

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

Probably a very basic question -

I have 2 tables **#favorites** and **#leaders**, each with a button in the bottom row.

And I want to display only one of tables, when I click a button.

So I'm trying the following and it kind of works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $('#favorites').hide();

        $('#show_favorites').click(function() {
                $('#leaders').fadeOut();
                $('#favorites').fadeIn();
        });

        $('#show_leaders').click(function() {
                $('#favorites').fadeOut();
                $('#leaders').fadeIn();
        });
});
</script>
```

but it happens at the same time, which looks awkward.

How do you wait for the **fadeOut()** to finish, before starting **fadeIn()**?

**UPDATE:**

I've change the code to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $('#favorites').hide();

        $('#show_favorites').click(function() {
                $('#leaders').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                        $('#favorites').fadeIn();
                });
        });

        $('#show_leaders').click(function() {
                $('#favorites').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                        $('#leaders').fadeIn();
                });
        });
});
</script>
```

And now it works better, but there is a new problem, when a button is clicked:

when the one table (grey in the screenshot below) disappears, the scrollbar jumps up. And then another table appears, but it is not visible anymore - you have to scroll down manually.

[image]

Any ideas please how to fight this?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in your titles and appending thanks/signatures to posts!

Comment: A "thank you", whilst polite, is unnecessary noise. This is not a forum or chat: it is a knowledge resource. The question body should just contain the question. And I mean the tags in titles: "jQuery - title here" is redundant; we already have a consistent, indexable tagging system.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, maybe - if you provide a pointer to SO owners saying so (because I suppose you're not a SO owner).

Comment: @Alexander Farber - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: There are no "owners". This is a community, with a FAQ, guidelines, common sense and a whole lot of Asperger's!

Comment: Of course there are owners: http://www.nytimes.com/2011/02/07/technology/07question.html

Comment: A "founder" is not an "owner", and the company that (yes, ok) legally "owns" Stack Overflow has no actual control over the community rules and guidelines. It's there to provide the infrastructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply a callback function to `fadeOut`, and call `fadeIn` in the callback. The callback function is executed when the `fadeOut` is complete:

```
$('#leaders').fadeOut(function() {
    $('#favorites').fadeIn();
});
```

See the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) for more info.

**Update** (based on updated question)

A potential solution to your scrolling problem:

```
$('#leaders').fadeOut(function() {
    $('#favorites').fadeIn(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, $(this).offset().top);
    });
});
```

This will cause the document to scroll automatically to the top of the element that's just faded in.

Comment: Thank you, but any ideas on improving scrolling? - please see the updated question

Comment: @Alexander - See my update. That will work, but it will sort of "jump" to the right position. It is possible to animate the scrolling though, if you'd rather do that.

Comment: Thank you! (not sure if I'm allowed to write this ;-)

Comment: @Alexander: Comments are different. :)

Answer (score 2):

You must make a callback like this:

```
$('#leaders').fadeOut(function()
{
    $('#favourites').fadeIn(); // execute after fadeOut has finished
});
```

Other:

```
$('#favourites').fadeOut(function()
{
    $('#leaders').fadeIn(); // execute after fadeOut has finished
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#leaders').fadeOut("slow", function() { $('#favorites').fadeIn(); });
```

fadeOut takes a callback which is called when fadeout is done.